# Getting a list of URLs for all Wikipedia articles in Physics category

Tags: url, vim, wikipedia

### Motivation, problem

I very often cite physics Wikipedia articles - which first requires googling to get the exact form of link, followed by copy pasting it. I want to make this method fast - for which I need the list of all physics articles.

#### Example:

Suppose I want to give a reference to `path integral formulation of quantum mechanics` in a problem I am solving.

Wikipedia does have a page on it, with the name "`Path integral formulation`". I won't know this however until I google "path integral quantum mechanics".

This process of searching is what I want to avoid. I claim I can cite these articles on the fly if I have a list of all physics articles in some file on my computer. (This is done by using vim plugins and some regex).

#### My ideas on getting article links

Wikipedia does have a index of physics articles, so maybe that could be leveraged?

I guess using Wikipedia API could help, but I am not sure and have never used it before. Or maybe some other vim plugin could help achieve this?

Can anyone help?

Comment: As it stands, your question is somewhat vague, it's hard to tell for sure what you're trying to accomplish... Can you give us a specific example? Perhaps a specific category and a specific article you'd like to find there? Note there's a specific Stack Exchange site for [vi.se], though in your case this might be more about scraping Wikipedia, so SO is maybe just as appropriate...

Comment: Not sure what you are after but if you are using windows, you could make powershell your default shell and execute something like `(iwr https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim).links | select -exp href | sort -un | where {$_ -match '^http'}` to get all http links from the Vim wiki webpage

Comment: The [categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) could help to get a list of article URLs in some category, although it doesn't sound like that's really what you are after.

Comment: Sorry for making it vague. The category was for physics. I stated my tool of choice as vim. Thanks for the suggestions - I will research these. Please re-read my question and see if you can help!